# trying to get product category image in woo-coomerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to get product category image.I ma using category image lugin for get category. https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/.
But problem is that when I am trying to fetch category image then showing null.
I am using this code for getting category image

```
<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image')) z_taxonomy_image(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => true
    ));

    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
        $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $shop_catalog_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'shop_catalog' );
        $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );?>

        <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $shop_catalog_img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" /></a>

    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query();
```